# Download PDF from byte[]

Tags: arrays, .net, angular, file

**Server side (Visual Studio 2015)**

I have a pdf stored in my server side. When called from the client via WebApi, I read and store the content on a variable with this instruction:

```
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
```

Then I send the file content to the client with the following instruction:

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, bytes);
```

**Client side (Angular 7)**
With FileSaver installed I receive the file content and it looks like this

> JVBERi0xLjUNCiW1tbW1DQoxIDAgb2Jq...eXBlL0NhdGFsb2cvUG

Then I try to download it in the following way:

```
this.fileService.fileDownload().subscribe(bytes => {
    const file = new Blob([bytes], {type: 'application/pdf'});
    saveAs(file, 'file.pdf');
}
```

With the following method in the fileService calling the Server API:

```
fileDownload(id): Observable<HttpResponse<any>>{
    const httpOptions = {
      'responseType'  : 'arraybuffer' as 'json'
    };
    return this.http.get<any>('http://localhost:55820/api/files/12',httpOptions);
  }
```

But the file is corrupted or not admited by Acrobat Reader.

I would also like it to work for other file types, having the file content in `byte[]`, the content-type definition (text/plain, application/pdf) and the file name with the extension. How can I standarize this process?

Answer (score 1):

**httpOptions** should be `{ responseType: 'blob' }`

Try like this:

```
fileDownload(id): Observable<HttpResponse<any>>{
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:55820/api/files/12',{ responseType: 'blob' });
}



this.fileService.fileDownload().subscribe(bytes => {
    saveAs(file, 'file.pdf');
}
```

Comment: Getting this error with that approach: `Type '"blob"' is not assignable to type '"json"'. [2322]`

Comment: Try  `{observe: 'response', responseType: 'blob'}`

Comment: Got `Type '"response"' is not assignable to type '"body"'` and `Type '"blob"' is not assignable to type '"json"'`

Comment: Remove `<any>` . You won't get this error anymore, sorry I didn't notice `any` earlier

Comment: Try this { 'responseType: 'blob' as 'json' }

Answer (score 0):

Response Type should be like responseType: 'blob' and after getting the blob response from observable you can pass blob response in the downloadFile(content) function where we will give type(E.g pdf, zip, etc) of file and name of the file and create an event to download.

```
download(id): Observable<Blob> {
    return this.http.get(this.downloadUrl + id 
    { 
        headers: this.getHeaders(), responseType: 'blob' })
        .pipe(catchError(this.handleError<any>('download')));
    }

this.downloadService.download(id).subscribe(data => {
    this.downloadFile(data);
});

downloadFile(content) {
    const fileName = 'dowmloadfile.pdf';
    const type = 'pdf';
    const e = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.download = fileName;
    a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(content);
    a.dataset.downloadurl = [type, a.download, a.href].join(':');
    e.initMouseEvent('click', true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    a.dispatchEvent(e);
}
```